# How to read a data from SQFLite in flutter

Tags: database, sqlite, flutter, dart

i'm using `sqflite` package and i want to read a data from it ,the data ins in a table named`my_table`in the table i want to read `name` property on it  and use it in a widget like text widget here is what i've tried \

```
list = await db.query('my_table', 'name');
     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
        return Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
            },
          ),
          body: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  height: 1000,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  child: Text('${list}'),
                ),    );
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide more information!

When you are using SQFLite:

### Reading:

https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md

> query is for reading a table content. It returns a list of map.

```
var list = await db.query('my_table', columns: ['name', 'type']);
```

I can recommend this [guide for SQFLite](https://medium.com/flutter-community/using-sqlite-in-flutter-187c1a82e8b)